# Apollo query from one component updates all the siblings in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-apollo

I have a Vue component with a list of items populated from a DB via Apollo:

```
<DeviceInfo camId="abcd"/>
<DeviceInfo camId="efgh"/>
<DeviceInfo camId="qwer"/>
```

When a response arrives via Apollo **all three** *DeviceInfo* components get updated with the same data at the same time. In the end they all have the very last response from the DB. I would expect the query to update its own component only.

**Any suggestions why the data is shared?**

What I know:

1. the DB responses are correct and contain data for the right camId as far as *apollo/data/updated* function.
2. Vue browser dev-tools show identical data objects for all *DeviceInfo* siblings.
3. I get the same behavior with *v-for*

```html
<v-flex v-for="item in data.listUserDevices.items" :key="item.device">
   <DeviceInfo :camId="item.device"/>
</v-flex>
```

Here is the full code of *DeviceInfo* component:

```html
<template v-if="hydrated">
      <h2>camId: {{camId}} / {{ data.getLatestDeviceState.items[0].device }}</h2>
</template>


<script>
import gql from "graphql-tag";

const DEV_INFO_QUERY = gql`query getLatestDeviceState($device: String)
  {
    getLatestDeviceState(device: $device) {
      items {
        device
        timestamp
        version
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default {
  name: "DeviceInfo",
  props: {camId: String},
  data() {
      return dt;
    },
  async mounted() {
    await this.$apollo.provider.defaultClient.hydrated();
    this.hydrated = true;
  },
  apollo: {
    data: {
      query:  () => DEV_INFO_QUERY,
      variables: function() { 
        return {device: this.camId}
      },
      update: data => {
                return data;
      }
    }
  }
};

  let dt = {
    data: {
      hydrated: false,
      getLatestDeviceState: {
        items: [{device:"Loading ..."}]
      }
    }
  };

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dt` (short for *"data template"* I assume) is defined in your component **definition** so all instances would share the same object.

An easy solution is to use it as a template but break the object reference in your `data` function, ie

```js
data() {
  return {...dt}
}
```